# How to add upstream job in Jenkins DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I can make a downstream job with the DSL plugin for Jenkins:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#downstream

How can I make an upstream job (same thing...just specified in a difference place)?

In the UI, it's under Triggers: "Build after other projects are built".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently that's not possible. The Job DSL plugin generates the configuration XML used internally by Jenkins. The upstream job is not part of that XML, Jenkins generates the information at runtime. So if you specify the upstream in a job, what Jenkins does is setting the downstream in that upstream job and persists that. And that's something that the Job DSL currently can not do.

Answer (score 0):

I define specific jobs that I want to be the upstream and define downstream jobs since that is specified in Jenkins DSL. This has worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

`upstream` method is available since Jenkins 1.33:

```
job('example') {
    triggers {
        upstream('some-upstream-job-name')
    }
}
```

See https://YOUR.JENKINS.DOMAIN/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.upstream